# Are there any commercial ecom & cms packages for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system

Are there any commercial ecommerce and CMS type packages for Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 0):

As far as CMS go : see here

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#Ruby_on_Rails

but if you also meant 'commercial cms', the quoted ones are MIT licensed

Answer (score 0):

There are some pre-built things that cost a little bit of money at [RailsKits](http://railskits.com/).

However, most of the good stuff is open sources, perhaps simply because it is a challenge to obfuscate Rails code.  For example, [ActiveMerchant](http://www.activemerchant.org) was extracted from the [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/) service, which was built in Rails.

Comment: Shopify chose to extract ActiveMerchant themselves - it wasn't the case that a 3rd party extracted it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean a system to create an e-commerce using RoR ? 
if that is, check out http://spreecommerce.com/

I never tried it myself, but it's the top app on http://www.opensourcerails.com